# asp.net core web api post fields always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

for years I've used previous versions of asp.net (MVC and WebForms) and now after a 2 year break of not using asp.net I decided to try out the new version on top of AWS Lambda using [this library](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet) and it's literally been hours and I still can't get it to ajax-post an object! I'm on Ubuntu running VS Code.

As the title says I either get a null object or if the object manages to have any properties their values are always null. If someone could help I would very much appreciate it. Here's a snippet of the front-end code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // var data = $('form').serialize();
    var data = {
        Name: $("input[name='name']",this).val(),
        Email: $("input[name='email']",this).val(),
        FindUs: $("input[name='find-us']",this).val(),
        Newsletter: $("input[name='newsletter']",this).val(),
        Message: $("textarea[name='message']",this).val()//,
        //TODO:
        //GRecaptchaResponse: $("input[name='g-recaptcha-response']",this).val()
    };

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/contacts',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            console.log('Data received: ');
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            //...
        },
        error: function(response) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

}

Here's the controller code (I'm omitting the namespace) (here's where most of my "grievances" have been documented...):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Contact contact)
    {
        //also tried:
        //public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Object contact)
        //public JsonResult Post([FromForm]Contact contact)
        //public JsonResult Post([FromForm]Object contact)
        //public JsonResult Post(Contact contact)
        //public JsonResult Post(Object contact)
        //public JsonResult Post(string Name, string Email, ...)
        // but always get null properties or a "System.Object" with no fields


        try
        {
            var myContact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(contact.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //always crashes
        }

        Type myType = contact.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            //doesn't even go into this foreach loop
            //and when it does the values are always null

            object propValue = prop.GetValue(contact, null);
        }

        string stringContact = contact.ToString();

        try 
        {
            Contact anotherContact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(stringContact);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //get “Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0”
        }

        var statusReturn = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        statusReturn.Add("status", "success");
        return Json(statusReturn);// on a good note, the front end picks this up and says all good...
    }
}
```

Here's the model:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string FindUs { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Newsletter { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    // [MaxLength(500)]
    // public string GRecaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

And finally here's Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public const string AppS3BucketKey = "AppS3Bucket";

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // Pull in any SDK configuration from Configuration object
        services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

        // Add S3 to the ASP.NET Core dependency injection framework.
        services.AddAWSService<Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //serve index.html by default (and ONLY serve index.html)
        DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

        loggerFactory.AddLambdaLogger(Configuration.GetLambdaLoggerOptions());
        app.UseMvc();

        //enable wwwroot
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

thanks

**UPDATE**

There are a ton of warnings when I run the website as you can see below (I am running "dotnet restore"):

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (clrdbg) with Visual Studio
Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and
test your applications.

---

Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/Repos/website_Some.software/backend/SomeSoftwareWebAPI/src/SomeSoftwareWebAPI/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/SomeSoftwareWebAPI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.ComponentModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.AppContext.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.IO.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Globalization.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Runtime.Handles.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/9.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Private.Uri.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/3.3.0.2/lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/AWSSDK.Core/3.3.7/lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/AWSSDK.S3/3.3.5.2/lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.S3.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.5/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.Text.Encodings.Web/4.0.0/lib/netstandard1.0/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Buffers.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives/4.1.1/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/4.1.0/lib/netstandard1.5/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.Collections.NonGeneric/4.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.Collections.Specialized/4.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/System.ComponentModel.Primitives/4.1.0/lib/netstandard1.0/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/home/someuser/.nuget/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Core/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting starting 
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.3/System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting started 
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /home/someuser/Repos/website_Some.software/backend/SomeSoftwareWebAPI/src/SomeSoftwareWebAPI
Launching browser (xdg-open http://localhost:5000)
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

**And finally**

I did have to downgrade a library to match aws's version, but I can't remember specifically which library it was, but after that all my unit tests passed.

I When I run "nuget restore" I get "This folder contains no solution files, nor packages.config files". And yes that's right, packages.config doesn't exist anywhere in the folders I've checked. I'm I supposed to not use the nuget command and let dotnet restore deal with it?

I've been reluctant to do this on Windows because this shouldn't require you to install Windows somewhere and then install Visual Studio with all the required extensions and updates in order to get a working project... if that's the case then there's no point in making asp.net core cross platform in the first place... Maybe I won't have any of these problems next time I try asp.net core + lambda for a future project... whenever that might be

Comment: Are you rly trying to send POST request to `/api/contacts` where `ContactsController` dont have `Post` action as dafult? Remove route from controller, add to your `Post` action [Route("api/contacts")] and ten check

Comment: Why are you trying to deserialize the model that was **already deserialized and bound by the model binder**? `contact` should not need any further deserializing on your part.

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, I am always able to hit a breakpoint within the action itself, so I'm guessing routing is working..

Comment: Your second problem is stringifying the data here: `data: JSON.stringify(data)`. Just set it like this: `data: data`.

Comment: Hi @juunas, removing stringify didn't work, also the first problem isn't really a problem, it was just me playing around with the object when I had the parameter set as type Object rather than Contact

Comment: Can you check with F12 tools that you are actually sending a JSON object like `{ "Name": "Test", "Email":"test@test.com" }`?

Comment: @juunas yeah, I'm alerting and also logging the contents of the json object

Comment: Can you upload project to github/other site? I want to try it myself with debugger

Comment: @J.Doe I thought about it but the front-end code has info that isn't meant to be publicly available yet, however I provided all the info I could in this question in the hope that it would be easier for someone to create a project, copy/paste the back-end code and then build a hard-coded data object in javascript

Comment: @J.Doe I might be able to create a dummy project and post it on github sometime tomorrow after work, hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will wait and try again in the future once all the relevant libraries are out of beta/rc.

Answer (score 0):

I created own project based on code in thread and find solution. Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` from `$.ajax`. After this it worked to me

Comment: I made that change and didn't work for me, do you have the project on github? Maybe there's something else I missed, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not a web api project, it's an mvc with views and no static html files, also it looks like it was created with visual studio (probably) due to the project files in it. Thank you for having a look, however I'm strongly suspicious that there's a configuration error somewhere. I'm trying again with the latest version of asp.net core web api without aws integration.

Comment: don't get me wrong I appreciate the effort you put in creating the project and adding the ajax request code and all, but in this case I'm debating whether I'll have to close this question as no matter what I change it just doesn't work, there's also a lot of warnings, also I am aware that a lot of the tools/frameworks being used here are not final versions yet, so I guess I'll have to wait for another project in the future and check it out again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able deploy this to Lambda with the Contact object filled in. The only change I made was in your Javascript change the url the ajax call goes to include the API Gateway stage name "/Prod/api/contacts".

Is there anything interesting in the CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function? I was getting null for a while because the JSON I was sending in the Ajax was causing a ModelState error because the values didn't match the DataAnnotations in the Contact object.

Comment: Thank you, I gave up on this a few days ago, I never knew what the problem was. I created the project again but through yeoman generator and then... again... had to spend some time getting the controller and the js code working together and passing the data... it took me a while... but this time it worked. I guess the issue had nothing to do with AWS. I hope in the future to get a book or do a course that gives me a good run-down on all the many things AWS has to offer, at the moment I don't have the time so I decided to go with the hosting providers that I'm already familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I am not sure exactly what resolved it, but I did find one difference. I installed "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" v 1.0.3 via NuGet while trying to find the source of the issue. This caused many of the other .Net Core packages to update from 1.0.0 to 1.0.3. Now it works. Perhaps there was a bug?